# Google Analytics Behaviour Flow not recognising query parameters

Tags: google-analytics

A site I'm working on uses the same path with query parameters used for different pages, E.g.

```
Dashboard.aspx?did=1
Dashboard.aspx?did=22
Dashboard.aspx?did=14&4
```

Google Analytics seems to group them all on the path value, effectively ignoring the query parameters and not showing a correct behaviour flow.

Is there any way to make GA recognise parameters as different pages?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show a screenshot of a report result, pls

Comment: @MichelePisani screenshots added

Comment: Seems that 4.1k haven't a querystring parameter, show landing page repor screenshot pls (from the dedicate report)

Comment: @MichelePisani I've added the landing page report. The Dashboard.aspx the actual homepage of the site where users land when they login.